# MacOS after change of Motherboard

Tags: macos, startup, ssd, motherboard

If I want to change the motherboard of a MacBook with a new one and I install on it the same SSD I had on the previous motherboard that has installed the OS and everything.

When I boot the Mac with this new motherboard, do I have to re-install the OS from scratch or all my datas remain on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS is installed on the SSD. Most installations are non-specific: they will run on any Mac that the OS supports.

In any case: reinstalling the OS normally leaves your data intact on the volume. And you've got a backup in the event of something going wrong and your files being accidentally deleted. Of course you have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so If I change the motherboard but I still use the same SSD (OS included) I don't need to re-install the operative system, right?

Comment: There is one notable (but somehow esoteric) exception: iMac Pros with a T2 chip. In theory the flash chips (custom made for/by Apple) can be removed. Since their content is preencrypted, they won't work (decrypt/boot) with a new motherboard (+ a new T2).